# Select a record which doesn't have a specific task among the group set

Tags: sql

In below table i'm trying to get the workId along with template Id which doesn't have a specific TaskID. Each workId can have multiple Tasks but they don't necessarily have same set of TasksIDs.

E.g I want to get the workIDS which don't have TaskID T02
which I would get

W03 and W05 as a result

Table name: WorkTaks
 [image: Table: WorkTasks]

I tried to the following query but i didn't get the exact results

```
select workID from WorkTasks
where TaskID != 'T02'
```

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of table to your question. 
Instead, edit your question and include the table in textual form

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery

```
select distinct workID from WorkTasks a
where not exists 
  (select 1 from WorkTasks b where a.workID =b.workID and  TaskID = 'T02')
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is aggregation:

```
select workID
from WorkTasks
group by workID
having sum(case when TaskID = 'T02' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows that match the condition (`= 'T02'`).  The `= 0` says there are none.